# cpio's file on disk is not older; skipping — how to suppress this warning?

Tags: macos, command-line

I create shadow copies of a directory containing 50K+ images (I don't remove them from the card until they're in three other places). Every time I add images to the master, I update the shadow copies using cpio (`find . | cpio -pdmv destination`).

On Leopard, the above command gives me a list of all the (new) images being added to the shadow copies while silently ignoring the images that haven't changed.

After upgrate to ML, cpio now insists on advising me about every file that it didn't copy, i.e. `cpio: ./some-file: File on disk is not older; skipping.` In my case I get fifty thousand of these spurious (and obvious) messages, drowning out the files I'm interested in seeing. Removing the `-v` doesn't help and neither does `--quiet`.

I could redirect stderr; however, I do want to know if any real errors occurred like destination full.

Comment: considered using rsync instead?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround of course is to filter the output of cpio using grep; however, this is a chunk of extra typing. What I really want is the Leopard behavior.

```
cd master-directory
(
    find . | cpio -pdmv /first/shadow/destination
    find . | cpio -pdmv /second/shadow/destination
) 2>&1 | grep -v -e'skipping' -e'^[:space:]*$'
```